# Prove that a continuous inverse-transformation of $f: [0,1) \cup \{ 2 \} \to [0,1]$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, transformation, inverse

I am having this transformation $f: [0,1) \cup \{ 2 \} \to [0,1]$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x  & x \neq 2
\\1 & x = 2
\end{cases}$$

I've already proved that it is continuous.

---

Question: Is there a continuous inverse-transformation of this transformation?

---

My thoughts:
Because f is continous and strictly increasing, then f has an
inverse function $ f^{-1}: [0,1] \to [0,1)  \cup \{ 2 \} $

Comment: [Are you going to make us do your whole homework assignment in little chunks?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069380/is-f-0-1-cup-2-to-0-1-continuous)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It's an exercise of a mock exam, but I have no solutions and the prof do not publish any solutions. So I try to write my own solution. Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is a bijection, so an inverse definitely exists. You could probably write that function down by hand if you needed to.

As for continuity: One theorem about continuous functions is that the image of a connected topological space under a continuous map is also connected. What does that tell you about the continuity of the inverse function?

Answer (score -1):

Because f is continous and strictly increasing, then f has an
inverse function $ f^{-1}: [0,1] \to [0,1[  \cup \{ 2 \} $